# what is the equivelant of get_global_pos from version 2.0 in 3.0?

Tags: gdscript

I want to make a turret that is shooting lazers and i watched a tutorial on it. The person in the video used `(scenename).position(get.node("Position2D").get_global_pos())` in order to spawn a projectile on the potition 2d. When i run this code, the game freezes and the debugger says "*Invalid call. Nonexistant function 'get_global_pos' in base 2D*". In the comments someone said that the tutorial is using 2.0 godot and that in 3.0 you dont use get_ and instead of pos you put potition, so i tried changing `get_global_pos` to `global_position` but it didnt work. i am very new to this and if you want any further information please let me know

Answer (score 1):

As you already found out, global_position is the equivalent to get_global_pos.

The difference is, that global_position is no function but a member.

So instead of:

```
(scenename).position(get.node("Position2D").get_global_pos())
```

you have to write:

```
(scenename).position = get.node("Position2D").global_position
```